# Unknown app version appears in Google Analytics data

Tags: android, piracy

I have an Android app published to Google Play Store (and its apk file is also published to some Chinese stores by somebody that I don't know). Today I noticed a very strange situation in Google Analytics data: I never release version 1.6.3, but I noticed it is there, having 37 sessions and keep increasing. I notice that all 37 sessions are from China. I can understand if they just publish my apk file to a store, but how can they modify my app version as well? And what can I do for this?

[image: Unknown app version]

Comment: Check black market in China stores. They may clone your app, change your App version & distribute without your authorization.

Comment: @Raptor so what can I do for this?

Comment: change your Google Analytics tracking code by using a new profile.

Comment: that's just a temporary solution. If I change my Analytics code then they will again edit my new apk.... Is there anything I can do to prevent this editing of my app? And is this kind of piracy popular for most Android app?

Comment: Did you use `proguard` to protect your codes?

Comment: No I did not. I thought `proguard` is only effective for obfuscating my source code, not things like app version, app name, package name.... But I'm not sure though. Will it help in this case?

Comment: They always can modify your app as well as app version but with proguard it is much harder.