# Why do I see an App Version Code as 'Unknown' in Google Playstore Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an Android App which is live in the Playstore and I was analysing the ratings for different version codes. I found something which doesn't actually make much sense to me.
In the list of apps with version codes, there happens to be a version code labeled as `Unknown` 
Each and every app which I had released had proper version codes with it (or else the playstore itself won't allow me to publish).
I am wondering from where this `Unknown` come from.
If anyone else had faced the same issue and have an explanation for the same, please help me grasp an explanation.

Attaching the screenshot for further clarity.
[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the quote form different [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unknown-app-version-on-google-play-worst-ratings-how-do-you-deal-with-that.495841/):

> I contacted Google Play about this a while ago and they finally
>   answered and offered a likely explanation about why the "Unknown"
>   version(s) are the worst rated: If a user uninstalls the app, and
>   after that decides to rate it, then the version will appear as unknown
>   because the system can't figure out what version exactly the rating is
>   referring to since the app is no longer on the user's device. And the
>   users who are most likley to uninstall AND rate the app are those who
>   really disliked it, hence the low ratings.

But in my case `Uknown` version doesn't have the lowest rating. It has the average.

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown" indicates an unknown or invalid sender ID. You may check this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105637/unknown-app-version-appears-in-google-analytics-data). One workaround given is to change your Google Analytics tracking code by using a new profile. Also, make sure that you use [ProGuard](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/help/proguard.html) to protect your codes.

Comment: Currently, I don't use Google Analytics in my app. This thing is showing up in the Playstore console. And yeah, Proguard is enabled in my project since v1 of the app. I went through the link before posting this question but did not find it much helpful.